# Best Encryption Algorithm for long passwords

Tags: c#, aes, rijndael

Recently I implemented AES/Rijndael-256 into a component to store passwords. Recently I tried to store a longer password of character length 36 and when decrypting this password from the database the implementation fails due to and invalid padding error. This issue doesn't occur with shorter passwords.

The current implementation:

```
   public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        // Salt and IV is randomly generated each time, but is preprended to encrypted cipher text
        // so that the same Salt and IV values can be used when decrypting.  
        var saltStringBytes = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        var ivStringBytes = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
        {
            var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
            using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.BlockSize = 256;
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                using (var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            // Create the final bytes as a concatenation of the random salt bytes, the random iv bytes and the cipher bytes.
                            var cipherTextBytes = saltStringBytes;
                            cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).ToArray();
                            cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(memoryStream.ToArray()).ToArray();
                            memoryStream.Close();
                            cryptoStream.Close();
                            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm no cryptographer but I assume this is due to the limitations of the AES/Rijndael max key size of 256 bits.

Are there some other recommended encryption methods which would support longer passwords?

Comment: @John yes correct. This has nothing to do with User Authentication.

Comment: I'm relieved to hear that :-)

Comment: Do not store passwords - store secure hashes of passwords. If your store gets hacked, you won't leak passwords.

Comment: @xxbbcc I mistakenly removed my question, but we've already clarified OP isn't doing that :)

Comment: @John Ah, ok. I guess I'm leaving my comment then for future readers.

Comment: @xxbcc Indeed, it's a good comment to leave for that purpose.

Comment: CBC mode can encrypt anything as long as you like. So, no, there is no fundamental restriction here. You just made a mistake (which I am still looking for)

Comment: Im any other case I would. This scenario requires a layer of security whilst being able to retrieve the unencrypted values using the privatr key when needed though.

Comment: note that you have not shown us the code that fails

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I solved the issue and the cause was unrelated to my question.